# Tweaking our Private Monero Pool

Tags: monerod, mining-pools

We set up a private pool and are mining at about 9KH/s, at least for now.  All of our miners are using the same XMR address, so we are not concerned with sending out payments.

What should I set the vardiff to in a situation like this?  Are there any other settings we should consider that would help the pool find a block more often, or do the settings even matter for that?

The server running the pool is fairly beefy.  We have about 32 devices mining to it and resources are barely taking a hit, so I am not concerned with this at all.

The devices have a varying range of H/s, some at only 150, some at 900, and currently all are pointing to the same port.  All this is CPU at the moment...we are waiting for our first block to invest in some GPUs!

Answer (score 1):

Whatever the difficulty, you have the same expected return in the long run, so it does not matter. If you use a difficulty that's twice as high, you'll find half as many shares. A higher difficulty will just increase the variance. Some people say "but it can mean this miner never finds a share so it's wasted", but that's hindsight bullshit since they won't complain when the worker gets lucky and finds way more than its expected share.

If it's your own pool, shares don't matter anyway. Whether or not a miner gets a share, you only get some monero if its difficulty is at least the current target, so any share with less difficulty is pointless.